# Why are my ASP.NET webforms controls not rendering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a feeling I'm missing one small thing.  I have very simple page, created from the ASP.NET templates in VS2010.  My Default.aspx consists of simply the following code.  The Site.Master page is doing what it's supposed to.

```
<%@Page 
    Title="Home Page" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="UserControlTest._Default" %>

<%@Register 
    TagPrefix="tsi" 
    Namespace="UserControlTest.Controls" 
    Assembly="UserControlTest" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <!-- HERE BE DRAGONS -->
    <tsi:BigHelloBanner   runat="server" />
    <tsi:SmallHelloBanner runat="server" />

</asp:Content>
```

BigHelloBanner contains this:

```
<%@Control 
    Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    Visible="true"
    CodeBehind="BigHelloBanner.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="UserControlTest.Controls.BigHelloBanner" %>

<h1>HI!</h1>
```

Both the codebehind files in both objects are empty, and inherit from `UserControl`.  The behavior is the same inheriting from `Control`.  When I view-source on the rendered output, nothing from the HelloBanners is output, except some newlines.  The HERE BE DRAGONS comment is visible, which indicates to me that the master page and all that works fine.  I am expecting to see the `<h1>HI!</h1>` markup in the output as well.  What am I missing?  This seems really basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that you're referring to the empty code-behind class instead of the ASCX file with the output. Use the `src` attribute in your `@Register` directive:

```
<%@Register 
    TagPrefix="tsi" 
    TagName="BigHelloBanner" 
    Src="BigHelloBanner.ascx" %>
```

Comment: This answered my primary question but I think it's going to cause a followup about how to change the controls out at runtime.  I'll see what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the src attribute here where is your control held ?

```
<%@Register 
    TagPrefix="tsi" 
    Namespace="UserControlTest.Controls" 
    Assembly="UserControlTest"
    src="?" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since BigHelloBanner is a web user control, you should try registering it like this:

```
<%@Register TagPrefix="tsi" TagName="BigHelloBanner" Src="~/pathToUserControls/BigHelloBanner.ascx" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you still need to give an ID to each control instance?

Comment: An ID seems to be automatically generated if I don't add one manually.